# Populating table cells from a external list file in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ipad

If I were to use the split table view controller (for iPad) rather than hard code the contents of the table to populate the view, can I import the information (including pictures) to populate the cells? Leading to an easy way to update the information held in the table?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at Apple code samples, like [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html), especially the ones regarding [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to understand how to fill a table.
2. A simple [property list](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) file should fit your needs. They are easy to create/edit with Xcode and easy to read with code, like `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path]`...